# Dynamic Columns Cross Apply

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm having some difficulty creating a dynamic `cross apply` script.

The source data looks like following:

```
LedgerLink  AccPrev_iBranchID   PrevBal01   PrevBal02   PrevBal03   PrevBal04   PrevBal05   PrevBal06   PrevBal07   PrevBal08   PrevBal09   PrevBal10   PrevBal11   PrevBal12
1442    0    30,056.02   31,506.93   91,055.50   92,885.87   150,895.98      180,883.31      237,646.90      266,985.71      299,143.65      330,267.37      371,292.29      384,210.25 
1502    0    (8,055.00)  (0.00)  (0.00)  (0.00)  (0.00)  (54,588.00)     (25,196.29)     (25,196.29)     (25,196.29)     (3,157.50)  (4,365.00)  (3,157.50)
1543    0    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)    (330,472.91)
```

I've developed the following script to have all the previous values in one column:

```
declare @columns varchar(max)

select @columns = stuff((select ',' + '('''+ Column_Name+''', PrevValue)'
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where   TABLE_NAME = 'AccPrev'
and     COLUMN_NAME like 'PrevBal%'
--group by COLUMN_NAME
order by ORDINAL_POSITION
for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')

--select    @columns

select
    LedgerLink
,   AccPrev_iBranchID
,   Prev.*
from    AccPrev
cross apply
( select @columns)Prev(PrevValue)
```

It keeps giving me the following results, which is not what I want:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It gives you exactly what you are asking for. What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: I need it give me the values, not the column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using Dynamic SQL to execute the built query string otherwise @columns is treated as a string and not a reference to actual columns.

See the first few examples from mssqltips here for a dynamic column example: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/